# Possible to REPLACE/REPLACE and then CAST a DE value in a SQL query?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

We're writing SQL for an Automation to find orders that qualify for a promo based on spend.

The source DE has a `TEXT` field with a dollar sign `$`, the order value and some HTML `<br />` - i.e., `$199.01<br />` We're trying to remove these characters and convert the field to `decimal(18,2)` so the query can find orders that meet the minimum spend.

We've tried the following, and it passes validation but fails when run in the automation
`CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(ordervalue,'$',''),'<br />','') as ordervalue) as decimal(18,2)`

We've also tried 
`CONVERT(decimal(18,2),(REPLACE(REPLACE(ordervalue,'$',''),'<br />',''))) as ordervalue`

but no luck.

Any ideas out there? Is this a SQL issue or DE issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax.  Is that AMPscript?

Comment: added more information to the post

Comment: Thanks, George.  I wish I could help you with this one.   :(

Comment: Pretty sure the issue is with the Data Extension.

We are successfully able to pull the characters out of the field and place the data into a `TEXT` field, but the moment we try to `CAST` as `DECIMAL(18,2)`, the query fails.

Comment: Also exported the data and manually imported it into a `DECIMAL(18,2)` field and it worked fine... GAH!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is it always exactly that format? I think the issue may be with the replace function, you could try using substring + charindex instead:

```
select convert(decimal(10,2),substring(ordervalue,2,charindex('<',ordervalue)-2)) as ordervalue
```

Comment: The suggestion above will run, and will pull records, but fails when we try to insert `ordervalue` into the DE... makes me think the issue is with the data type in the DE, rather than the SQL.

Currently, the data type is `DECIMAL(18,2)`... and yes, we didn't use `Decimal(10,2)`